# Are there any house rules for combining Munchkin and Fluxx?

Tags: house-rules, munchkin, fluxx

It occurred to me that the Fluxx and Munchkin are quite similar games in that they are casual games that derive their fun from their theming.

Is it possible to combine the games?

Comment: I'm not going to say it's impossible, but "they are both casual games that derive their fun from their theming" is not actually an argument for why the games might be combinable.

Comment: Why not, they combined Munckin with Smash-up too ;-).

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but this actually is an idea that has occurred to me too. That said, I suspect it wouldn't be too easy, mainly because of the very different card-drawing and playing mechanics of the two games. You probably *could* design an add-on to Munchkin with some Fluxx-like mechanics such as changing rules (or, conversely, a Munchkin-themed Fluxx deck with a few mechanics borrowed from Munchkin), and maybe even reuse a few actual Fluxx cards in it, but it'd be far from a simple "mix the decks and add a few rules" mash-up like you can do between different Fluxx or Munchkin variants.

Comment: @dwjohnston Have you played both of these games?

Comment: I think these games derive their fun from chaos. Both games are largely built around the premise that the person who best survives the chaos wins. If you could figure out how to mix this aspect of both games...

Answer (score 3):

As much as I love Munchkin and Fluxx, the game mechanics are so different that combining them would just cause a headache. How would keepers interact with Kicking down the door? Do goals change the requirement to reach level 10? It would be so confusing and weird to play that I would suggest staying away from combining these card games. However, there were expansions for both games if you want to freshen up gameplay.